# Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML Document [...] error while trying to transform an XML into HTML with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert an XML into an HTML through an XSLT.

My XML is:

```
<FooterXmlModel>
  <Utente>foo@bar.it</Utente>
  <Today>03/04/2017 17:18:37</Today>
</FooterXmlModel>
```

My xslt is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <!--Footer-->
  <div>
    <b>User: </b>
    <p>© All Rights Reseved. P.IVA xxxyyyzzzwww</p>   -
    <xsl:value-of select="/FooterXmlModel/Utente"/>   -
    <xsl:value-of select="/FooterXmlModel/Today"/>
  </div>
  <hr style=" width 100%; height:2px; border-style:solid; margin:1px;clear:left;" />
  <div>
   <span>http://new.foo.it</span>
  </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have a function that accepts an xml document and its xslt and tries to convert it in a html document:

```
public string TransformToHtml(IPrintablePartXml document, IXPathNavigable xsltStyleSheet)
        {
            //XML Containing the actual document
            var xmlDoc = document.GetXmlContent();
            //resulting html file
            string htmlDoc = String.Empty;

            XPathNavigator xmlContent = new XPathDocument(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xmlDoc))).CreateNavigator();

            using (MemoryStream xslFoStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
                settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
                settings.Indent = true;

                using (XmlWriter xwriter = XmlWriter.Create(xslFoStream, settings))
                {
                    XslCompiledTransform transformer = new XslCompiledTransform(false);

                    transformer.Load(xsltStyleSheet);
                    transformer.Transform(xmlContent, _xsltExtensions, xwriter);

                    xwriter.Flush();

                    xslFoStream.Position = 0;

                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xslFoStream);
                    htmlDoc = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                return htmlDoc;
            }

        }
```

I Get this Error when I call transformer.Transform(xmlContent, _xsltExtensions, xwriter):

```
Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid
XML document. Make sure that the ConformanceLevel setting is set to 
ConformanceLevel.Fragment or ConformanceLevel.Auto if you want to write
an XML fragment.
```

I've read all the previous questions about this topic, but I couldn't figure out why I'm getting this error, since It seems to me that my XML is well-formatted.

Comment: Well the error message clearly tells you that `settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;` is wrong with the lind of output you have, set `settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSLT stylesheet attempts to create an XML fragment consisting of 2 `div` elements separated by an `hr` - with all three being siblings at the top level of the tree. A [well-formed XML document](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) has a single root element:

> [Definition: There is exactly one element, called the root, or
>   document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other
>   element.]

Comment: Note also: in the XDM data model, a document node with multiple element children is permitted, and the serializer will handle it (outputting an "external general parsed entity", which allows multiple top-level elements). But other destinations for your transformation output may not accept it: for example a SAXResult may complain.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
So It was due to the format of the xslt file that has multiple root elements. I thought that only the xml file to transform needed to be well-formatted.

Comment: @davideAlbertini The XSLT specification does allow the result to be an XML *fragment* (with multiple root elements). Apparently your processor,  under your current settings, is more strict then that.  --- BTW, it's *well-formed*, not *formatted*, and it's the result that has multiple root elements, not the XSLT file itself.